# Nativescript ScrollView gets cropped by gridview

Tags: html, css, android-layout, nativescript

I am making a Nativescript Android application in which I want a static header and footer and everything in between to be scrollable. To do this I use a gridlayout with a stacklayout for the header and footer and a scrollview to make everything inbetween scrollable.

The content in the scrollview has one stacklayout which needs to expand to the maximum it can get. This I also try to accomplish with a Gridlayout.

I am testing this on 2 emulators, 1 with a very small screen and 1 with a big screen. I can't get both to work at once. Either the small screen gets cropped or the big screen doesn't have it's stacklayout expanded.

Code and screenshots below.

```
XML:
<Page loaded="loaded" actionBarHidden="true">  
<GridLayout rows="auto,*,auto">
    <!-- Header -->
    <StackLayout height="15%" row="0" width="60%" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Image src="~/images/logo gezicht.png" stretch ="aspectFit"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <!-- Main -->
    <ScrollView width="80%" row="1" orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout rows="auto,auto,*" orientation="vertical" style="background-color: #ededed"> <!-- height="100%" -->

            <Label text="Welcome, let us start with a few questions!" horizontalAlignment="center" class="pageLabel" row="0"/>

            <StackLayout width="85%" height="10" class="settingFieldHeader" row="1"></StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="settingField" row="2" height="100%">
                <Label text="What is your name?" class="questionLabel" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
                <TextField text="{{ name }}" hint="Your name."/>
            </StackLayout>

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <StackLayout row="2" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Button text="Next" class="nextButton" tap="saveButton"/>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
</Page>

Css:

.pageLabel {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 22;
}

.settingFieldHeader{
    margin-top: 25;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #8FCBFA;
    border-radius: 20,20,0,0;
}

.settingField {
    padding: 25,15,25,15;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20;
}

.questionLabel{
    font-size: 20;
    color: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 50;
}

.nextButton {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 25,25,25,25;
}
```

[Screenshot of Gridlayout without height="100%", scrollable but not expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlOuN.png)

[Screenshot of Gridlayout with height="100%", not scrollable but expanded (I added some spaces to push the textbox out of the layout to show that it isn't scrollable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2hem.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [discourse.nativescript](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-scrollview-gets-cropped-by-gridview/5726/4?u=stefana):

```
<GridLayout rows="auto,*,auto">
    <!-- Header -->
    <StackLayout height="15%" row="0" width="60%" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Image src="~/images/logo gezicht.png" stretch ="aspectFit"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <!-- Main -->
    <ScrollView width="80%" row="1" orientation="vertical">

        <DockLayout style="background-color: #d3d3d3" stretchLastChild="true">

            <Label dock="top" text="Welcome, let us start with a few questions!" horizontalAlignment="center" class="pageLabel"/>

            <StackLayout dock="top" width="85%" height="10" class="settingFieldHeader"></StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="settingField">
                <Label text="What is your name?" class="questionLabel" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
                <TextField text="{{ name }}" hint="Your name."/>
            </StackLayout>

        </DockLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <StackLayout row="2" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Button text="Next" class="nextButton" tap="saveButton"/>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: please add little description also